# How to Make VB.NET Code Retrieving Single Rows from SQL Server Tables As Fast as VB6

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, adodb, recordset

We have been tasked with converting a legacy VB6 application to VB.Net.

The code conversion has been finished for some time  We are now testing.

Part of the suite of testing tools is the ability to run system load tests repeatedly.

We observe that the tests take significantly longer to run with the VB.NET version.

As part of the analysis, we created a test which load tests only the portion of the application which access the SQL database using ADODB.

This is where the performance issue resides.

In particular, the issue occurs in the retrieval of single rows, by key, from relatively small tables (e.g. 20 or so columns).

Each entry in a row of each table has a unique int key and a unique varchar key.

In both versions, retrieval is via a SQL Server stored procedure.  The key value is passed as an ADODB.Parameter appended to the ADODB.Command.  In fact, the same instance of the database is used in both versions (uses the same stored procedure).  Before each test, we delete all pre-existing rows in the tables.

The connection string to the database in both versions is:

Driver={SQL Server};Server=MYCOMPUTER\SQLEXPRESS;Database=THEDATABASENAME

The stored procedure for retrieval is:

```
SELECT * From Table1 WHERE TheKey = @pTheKey
```

where @pTheKey is the value of the ADODB.Parameter.

To get the following results, we first load each table with 5000 rows each.  The insertions take approximately the same elapsed time, although VB.Net is slightly faster.

The loading of the rows occurs in the order 5000 to 1 (i.e. backwards).

We then run retrieval tests which are:

1] From table 1, retrieve 10000 rows in order 1 to 5000;
2] From table 1, retrieve 10000 rows in random order;
3] From table 1, retrieve (or ask to retrieve) 10000 non-existent rows in random order.

In the above, the first 5000 retrievals are with the int key and the last 5000 retrievals are with the varchar key.

The test is repeated for table 2.

After retrieving each row, we check the data to ensure that the correct row has been retrieved (or not).

Here are typical timing results for the retrievals (all times in milliseconds):

VB6 Table 1 Test 1: 3926
VB6 Table 1 Test 2: 2740
VB6 Table 1 Test 3: 4444
VB6 Table 2 Test 1: 3882
VB6 Table 2 Test 2: 2596
VB6 Table 2 Test 3: 4635

.NET Table 1 Test 1:    241715
.NET Table 1 Test 2:    212798
.NET Table 1 Test 3:    238280
.NET Table 2 Test 1:    122237
.NET Table 2 Test 2:    75840
.NET Table 2 Test 3:    244343

The .NET retrievals take somewhere between 30 to 75 times longer.  The times are completely reproducible over multiple tests within 100 milliseconds or so.

The following is the VB6 code to perform the retrieval of the single row (or failure in the case of test type 3]).

```
Dim RecordSet As ADODB.RecordSet
Set RecordSet = sqladodbcommand.Execute
```

where sqladodbcommand is the ADODB.Command object with the appended ADODB.Parameter set to the key value.

The following is the .NET code to perform the retrieval of the single row (or failure in the case of test type 3]).

```
Dim RecordSet As ADODB.RecordSet
RecordSet = New ADODB.Recordset
RecordSet.Open(sqladodbcommand, , , ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)
```

Anticipating questions:

1] all SQL related code resides in one single module;
2] no other code is being run during the load test;
3] there is only one database connection active and that is the load test connection;
4] retrieving the Recordset value(s) from the returned Recordset has been stripped off to verify that extracting the data out of the returned Recordset object does not affect the times;
5] the VB6 reference to ADO is "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.0 BackCompat Library";
6] the .NET reference to ADO is "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library".

Any insights or suggestions gratefully received.

UPDATE (some days later):
After converting the source code from ADODB to ADO.NET, the inserts take approximately the same time as both VB6 and ADODB.

However, on the retrieval side, the retrievals are twice as fast (at least) as VB6 and over a hundred times faster than ADODB.

(For any newbies who may be reading this as part of a search, look at the interfaces in System.Data.SqlClient.)

We will be running more tests to compare the results for single record updates.

Comment: Are you testing the .NET application on XP?  Anything newer should be MDAC 6.0.  You can't even install 2.8 on Vista or newer...  It would be good to see all of the code you are using (ie: a [mcve])

Comment: And can you post a more complete repro of both the VB and VB.NET code?

Comment: Subby: The current test platform is Windows 7 Ultimate Dell M6500.  The VB6 project has 167,207 lines of code and the .NET project has 201,361 lines of code.  By minimal code you mean: creation of ADODB.Command, creation of ADODB.Parameter(s), connection to database, creation of RecordSet?

Comment: @DumbestGuyOnSaturn By minimal, I mean you can click the blue text and it will take you to a whole page that explains what it means.

Comment: You should be re-writing the ADODB code to use the native .Net [ADO.Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-overview) classes.  Using the COM interop ADODB library is adding overhead at each call to marshal between .Net and COM.

Comment: This may be what happens in the end.  So why are row inserts just as fast or faster in VB.NET? If what you are saying is true, this sounds like a huge Microsoft fail.  They promote "interface".  They have a responsibility to make certain that the interface responds more or less equally across language types.  At my end, we don't have any freedom to explain to the customer "Yeah, the upgrade sucks, but it is what it is."

Comment: In agreement with TnTinMn on this, if you've been tasked with converting this app to .net, why use old technology like ADODB.  Either do it properly or don't do it at all

Comment: I don't know if this will affect the performance, but in the article [Filling a DataSet with an ADO Recordset or Record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/aa720078(v=vs.71)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) it is recommended to use the ADODB PIA located in the "Program Files\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies" directory.  A quick inspection of that PIA revealed that it has some custom marshalers for parameters that the TLBIMP generated interop library does not have. It may be worth a try.

Comment: @DumbestGuyOnSaturn  It's 2020 - if you're just now getting around to updating a VB6 application for a paying customer, don't blame Microsoft.  You've had fifteen years.

Comment: I doubt a single insert is as fast. But , if you START a process, create all the objects, and then run the code, then most of the inter-op and marshaling is only done say one time, and once data starts to flow, then it not so bad. The issue(s) in most cases will be say a single operation to fetch some row or some such. The overhead for one operation is high to get or deal with one row. however, to pull 100 rows? Well, once all the marshalling has occurred, then at that point the overhead is done and not much of a issue. I guess the question is how much other 20 year code systems are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Hum, the problem is that ADO reocrdsets are un-managed code. As as result, .net will have to "marshal" constantly between managed and un-managed code. that includes the marshaling of the data types to/from the .net variable types. That going to cost.

I mean, you could try this code as a test:

```
    Dim t As DateTime
    Debug.Print("start")

    t = Date.Now

    Using con As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.Test3)
        Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * from tblHotels where ID  = @ID"
        Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, con)
        cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 19
        con.Open()
        Dim rst As New DataTable
        For i = 1 To 10000
            rst.Clear()
            rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        Next

    End Using

    Debug.Print("time = " & ((Date.Now.Ticks - t.Ticks) / 10000000).ToString)
```

Now I am running above on a dumpser fire laptop with a 1.7 ghz i3 (so VERY low end).

I get for above a time of  6.6428576 seconds, or of course  6642 mil secs.

I'm guess with better hardware, the above would drop again by half.

Now, given that you noted this is a VERY large application? It would be advantage to convert and use the .net sql provider objects as opposed to non managed code such as ADO.

The problem of course is that you have a large application, and I not all so sure it would be practical to convert (move away) from legacy ADO.

So, a big part of this is likely due to ADO being non managed code is going to fight tooth and nail against the native (and VERY cool .net CLR optimizers that can in most cases do a rather good work in terms of performance. However, the .net code optimizers only works on .net "managed" code, and not un-managed code libraries as was done.

Now, I could try the above code as ODBC, and also that of oleDB providers (and I am betting they both will perform similar as the sqlProvider I used above).

You could also try forcing your project to x64, but I not sure if x64 bit ADO providers are available.

So, right now and so far? I think this issue is much due to using un-managed ADO code here. I would say try a test stub simular to what I posted. (you have WAY better hardware then my dumpster budjet laptop that I tested above on).

A POSSILE migration could be using oleDB providers, as that should keep syntax similar, but then again, as noted above, I used native DataTable object. (those native .net objects such as datarow, datatable etc. are 100% the same if you use

```
sql provider in .net (best choice)
oleDB provider in .net (a good choice when migration from VB6)

ODBC provider in .net (I like this if you ever want to swap database in future
and in fact ODBC is a better choice then say oleDB providers. And ODBC is making a
strong comeback in the marketplace with robust re-connection options for say SQL Azure
```

And the last choice? Well, that would be using a external reference to the ADO legacy library.

The problem here really started when someone converted from VB6 to vb.net. That's when the jump and move away from ADO legacy (un-managed) should have occurred.

Anyway, give the above code a try. I am suggesting that all 3 .net providers I noted above should perform quite similar. And keep in mind that above was run on a bottom feeder laptop running a 1.7ghz.

Comment: Subby here: Thank you for your investment and this is useful information.  One of the issues we have, and this may be obvious to some but lost on others, is, we have to make an upgrade without touching the database.  We can change the executable, but we just can't install new database structures to conform to Microsoft dictates.  The database and stored procedure structure has to stand and stay in place for quick backout.  You know, some applications affect real people in real time in real ways.

Comment: @DumbestGuyOnSaturn This isn't in the least suggesting changing anything to do with the Database, merely the connection to the database.  As correctly stated, the change from adodb to ado.net should of happened at the very start of this migration.  Not knowing how big you project really is, you options are to re do the data access layer or suffer the consequences

Comment: Understood you have a "large" code base. The use of the .net sqlprovider will not really change anything in terms of the tables, or even use of store procs. What will change however is the use of the .net built objects like datarow, datatable etc. That will require some re-factoring when not using the ADO objects. So you don't need to "install" new database structures - you can well use existing. But only you can decide if the efforts are worth it. Perhaps you refactor some slow parts, and live with the rest. So the database and store procs are a non issue here - they remain "as is"